# Why does the following code go into an infinite loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, infinite-loop, goto

Consider the following code:

```
const char *s = "a   b    c  d !";
const char *p = s;

top:for(; *p; p++) {
    switch(*p) {
    case 0x20: 
    case '\n': 
        goto top;
    default: 
        putchar(*p);
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why it enters an infinite loop instead of stopping when `*p` is `NULL`? I had in mind the following: when `*p` is `0x20` or `\n` go to the beginning of the loop again, since it tests the condition and evaluates the expression `p++`.  So, I don't see a reason for it to loop infinitely, or I really don't get how the `goto` statement and `labels` work in the C programming language.

Comment: Obligatory: http://xkcd.com/292/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `goto top`, `p++` is not executed, because the for loop is started again from the beginning. Then you `goto top` again. And then again. And then again. And forever.

If you want your increment to work, use `continue` instead of `goto`. Or, better yet, do something even clearer:

```
for(p = s; *p != '\0'; p++) {
    switch(*p) {
    case 0x20:
    case '\n':
        // Do nothing.
        break;

    default: 
        putchar(*p);
    }
}
```

Oh, and by the way, avoid `goto` statements like the plague. Unless you're generating C code in an automated way and it's not supposed to be human readable, `goto` is virtually never a good idea.

Comment: Why is `p++` not executed? and `*p` is not too?

Comment: @Jack `*p` is executed, only `p++` is skipped, because the end of the loop is not reached.

Comment: @Jack Because on the first iteration of a for loop, the increment-decrement is never executed; it is only executed after the first iteration ends. But since you `goto` to a place that's before the for loop, it can't execute the increment. Instead, the for statement begins again *from the start*, doing another *first* iteration.

Comment: Very dangerous thing I have discovered today. I never knew that by doing `foo:for(;*p;p++) if(..)goto foo;` not all iteration is evaluated. That's `p` isn't incremented. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Jack The think you should have discovered today is that you should not be using `goto` at all.

Comment: Actually I know that must not use goto at all..  But I did it because I wanted to go to top of loop if such condition is true. The purpose is do all processing(it change some variable value that is processed in a below switch)  again if a character is seen.

Comment: @Jack The point is that, if you think you need to use `goto`, you should think again. Because you don't need `goto`. And I'm not talking of course just about this particular situation. I'm talking about all possible situations where you would think you neeed to use `goto`. So, next time you think "this can only be solved though a `goto`", know in advance that no, there are other ways :)

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
const char *s = "a   b    c  d !";
const char *p = s;

 for(; *p; p++) {
    switch(*p) {
    case 0x20: case '\n': continue;
    default: putchar(*p);
    }
  }
```

The reason is, your code is not completing even a single iteration and hence the p++ never comes to execution. When you continue instead of using label, it counts to one complete iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char *s = "a   b    c  d !";
const char *p = s;

top:
for(; *p; p++) {
    switch(*p) {
    case 0x20: 
    case '\n': 
        p ++;
        goto top;
    default: 
        putchar(*p);
    }
}
```

You have to use `p ++;` before `goto top;`, because going to `top:` means you are restarting the loop.

Comment: Using `goto` is not a good practice, I use `goto` when i have to handle error conditions.